# storing mouse position as variable and comparing with values to fire events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout, bounding-box

I'm in a position where I can't simply use a hover event, but I need to trigger mouseover and mouseout when the mouse is inside the area of a given element and when it leaves that area. It can be javascript, or jquery, or a mix. I haven't successfully been able to store the mouse positions as variables or figure out a way to tell when the mouse leaves the given area. My questions are each represented by '????' in the code.

```
function targetMouse() {
    var box = document.getElementById('CleanBox'),
        top = box.offsetTop,
        left = box.offsetLeft,
        right = left + box.offsetWidth,
        bottom = top + box.offsetHeight,
        mouseX = ????;
        mouseY = ????;

    if (left < mouseX > right && top < mouseY > bottom) {
        $('#CleanBox').mouseover();
    }
    else if (????) {
        $('#CleanBox').mouseout();
    }
}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: _"I need to fire mouseover and mouseout"_ - You need to _fire_ the events, as in _trigger_ them, or you need to do something in response to them? Why can't you use hover?

Comment: I can't use hover because I'm developing a plugin for rapidweaver and on occasion, rapidweaver will randomly put transparent elements right in front of other elements, so hover wouldn't always work.

Sorry for not being clear, and thanks for pointing it out, I need to trigger events. I'll edit that in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

.box {

```
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    background-color:yellow;
    border:2px solid;
}

<div id="popup">Mouse is on box</div>
<div id="box" class="box"></div>

var box = document.getElementById("box");
var top = box.offsetTop;
var left = box.offsetLeft;
var right = left + box.offsetWidth;
var bottom = top + box.offsetHeight;
var hoverState = false;
var popup = document.getElementById("popup");

popup.hidden = true;

function hoverCheck(evt) {
    var x = evt.clientX;
    var y = evt.clientY;

    if (x >= left && x <= right && y >= top && y <= bottom) {
        if (hoverState === false) {
            hoverState = true;
            console.log("mouseon");
        }
    } else {
        if (hoverState === true) {
            hoverState = false;
            console.log("mouseoff");
        }
    }

    popup.hidden = !hoverState;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", hoverCheck, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4W3ku/)